# OrientDB Embedded Multi-Node Local

Tags: java, orientdb

I have a Java application containing an embedded OrientDB (latest version as of writing). I use the local mode to read/write files in a specific location.

I would like to add additional application nodes.

I understand from the documentation that OrientDB supports distributed setups. But can just add multiple OrientDB nodes pointing to the same local filesystem directory? I do not need data replication at the moment. I would rather have all my application nodes using the same files.

Comment: Same files in same directory on same storage on same machine... why you think you need multiple nodes?

Comment: Customer often install multiple nodes of our application by default. Often for irrational reasons such as corporate policy / enterprise architecture strategies. Sometimes to distribute the application load across multiple JVMs. The application nodes may not be on the save server, but all server would share the same mount.